# Missing values from a subset of a numeric column using a numeric sequence in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, seq

I am trying to subset a numeric column with 3 decimal places using a sequence that represents an interval of interest. Here is an example:

```
# Dummy data frame
> df <- data.frame(a = seq(10), b = sample(seq(1,10,0.001), 10))

> df
    a     b
1   1 5.263
2   2 4.970
3   3 5.238
4   4 4.792
5   5 8.875
6   6 7.425
7   7 4.480
8   8 8.045
9   9 4.956
10 10 4.318

# Bin containing interval of interest
> bin <- seq(4,6,0.001)

# Subset of df%b using bin
> df$b[df$b %in% bin]
[1] 5.263 4.792 4.480 4.318
```

I also expected to see in the results 4.970, 5.238, 4.956... but they are missing.

Another function I came across to subset the data is the following:

```
> bin[findInterval(df$b, bin)]
 [1] 5.263 4.970 5.238 4.792 6.000 6.000 4.480 6.000 4.955 4.318
```

This method picks up all the data points I was expecting, however 4.956 is displayed as having been matched by 4.955 in the bin, which makes me wonder if the match is not occurring due to rounding errors. I also assume that the "findInterval" method displays the three 6s shown above because the values it is trying to match are beyond the upper limit of bin, which is 6 in this case.

My data requires 3 decimal places of precision and I am trying to extract values that fall within an interval around a mean. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Yep, sounds like floating point error; `all.equal` might be useful. [Here's some relevant reading.](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) Also, put `set.seed` at the start of your example if you're going to use `sample`, so people can get the same numbers as you.

Comment: @alistaire, thanks for the tips on posting questions and floating point errors. I fixed the issue by applying sprintf("%.3f", ...) to both df$b and bin, forcing all elements to have only 3 decimal places. Printing df$b and bin to 16 digits (i.e. print(df$b, digits = 16)) revealed the hidden decimals beyond 3.

Comment: Instead of converting to "character" with `sprintf` you could use `df$b[round(df$b, 3) %in% round(bin, 3)]`. If you, indeed, want to find values that fall inside an interval, you could use something like `(df$b >= start) & (df$b <= end)` (or, even better, use `findInterval`) instead of testing for exact equality with all the generated values inside the interval.

Comment: @alexis_laz, thanks for the heads up. I didn't realize I had turned the variable into text using `sprintf`. Both the `round` and start/end options are working out for me inside a `dplyr` statement.